# Spring Social losing auth token on redirect

Tags: spring, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I'm trying to use Spring Social Facebook login along side form login, more or less following the guide here: http://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security, only using header-based session management rather than cookies. Right now the login is successful. Facebook sends a `302` to my server at `/api/signin/facebook`, and my server sends a `302` to the post-sign-in url I've set on my `ProviderSignInController` along with the `x-auth-token` header. The issue is that when following the last redirect my browser throws away the auth token.

I think I want to just add the auth token as a query param on the final redirect uri, but I don't know how to intercept the final response. I've called `setSignInInterceptors` on my `ProviderSignInController` but that seems to be ignored after the first sign in. How can I keep my session information when it's not a cookie?

Answer (score 0):

Just added the token as a query parameter and returned it from my custom SignInAdapter.signIn method. I feel like there's probably a better solution but I needed something.